# VSCode not adding closing brackets with correct settings

Tags: json, typescript, visual-studio-code, github-copilot

My vscode editor is set to automatically add closing brackets/parenthesis but does not add them. This is a new issue that only recently began. Has anyone else experienced this issue with global vscode settings?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This may be caused by the new vscode extension `GitHub Copilot`.

Update your `settings.json` like the following...

```json
// Must specify rule by language
"[typescript]": {
  "editor.autoClosingBrackets": "always"
}
```

This can become an issue as the new `GitHub Copilot` will override some settings in `settings.json` file.  In order to take back control from the `GitHub Copilot` extension you must specify some rules like `editor.autoClosingBrackets` on a **per lang** basis.

Comment: Please update your answer with the actual configuration you are using rather than a screen shot.

Comment: I updated the original answer to reflect what I did to fix the issue. :)

Comment: You can now change this for all languages in the UI Settings. Open `Settings` and search on `brackets`.  The dropdown for `Auto Closing Brackets` has several options including `always` and `beforeWhitespace`.